# Check for blank date when reading an SqlDataReader

Tags: c#, ado.net

I am populating my object with results from a database via a sqlDataReader like so:

```
foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
{
  wt = new WorkTasksDto
  {
    CompletedBy = dr.IsNull("CompletedBy") ? (DateTime?)null : (DateTime?)dr["CompletedBy"]
  };
}
```

As you can see im checking for a DbNUll, but one of my records for my date field is blank. Not null, just like an empty varchar field and when I try to do my DateTime cast, I get an invalid cast error.

How do I check for a blank field as well as a DbNull field?

Comment: If the field is "blank" the data type of the column cant be `DateTime`

Comment: You're exactly right, my field is not a datetime field in sql server. Its a varchar. Thanks

Comment: Why do you use a varchar field for a datetime?

Comment: I didnt...this is a database that was setup in 2000 and i inherited it. I assumed it was datetime based on the name

Comment: @user1202717 That is very bad, you know different cultures formats the date differently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not very clean but this seems to work.

```
foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)                  
{                       
     DateTime myDate;
     if(dr.IsNull("CompletedBy")) 
         myDate = DateTime.MinValue;
     else
     {
         if(DateTime.TryParse(dr["CompletedBy"].ToString(), out myDate) == false)
             myDate = DateTime.MinValue;
     }
     wt = new WorkTasksDto                              
     {                                  
         CompletedBy = (myDate == DateTime.MinValue ? null : myDate);
     };         
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If the column type is `DateTime` the value cant be "blank".
If the column type is `string`, you should check for null and blank and than parse the value rather than cast:

```
CompletedBy = dr["CompletedBy"] == null || dr["CompletedBy"] == "" ?
              null : 
              DateTime.Parse(dr["CompletedBy"], CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

If you know you have other values than blank that are not parsable to `DateTime` use `TryParse` instead

If the column type is `object` and you mix different types you need to verify the type first and than cast.

```
CompletedBy = dr["CompletedBy"] != null && dr["CompletedBy"] is DateTime ?
              (DateTime)dr["CompletedBy"] : 
              null;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `DateTime.TryParse()` http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tryparse.aspx

```
DateTime completedDate;

DateTime.TryParse(reader["CompletedDate"].ToString(), out completedDate);

if(completedDate == DateTime.MinValue)
{

}
```

Comment: I a changed my code to this                                      CompletedBy = dr.IsNull("CompletedBy") ? (DateTime?)null : DateTime.Parse(dr["CompletedBy"].ToString()), 
now i get "string was not recognized as a valid DateTime" which is true cause its blank